# Calling a Function from a class inside an Array List

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm working on a game which features a simulated Windows XP interface, but I'm stuck at the taskbar now.

I have a class called `InternetExplorer` and everytime the player clicks on a button, a new instance of that class opens. I'm storing these instances in an Array List. Now, if the player clicks a program in the taskbar, the corresponding form should be focused. I wanted to do it like this:

1. Get the index of the selected icon.
2. Focus on the form with the same index in the Array List.

But this doesn't seem to work, as I can't find a way to call any functions of a class in an Array List.

I'd apprechiate any answers,
Mika // OneByte_

Comment: `ArrayList` isnt strongly typed - they can only hold `Object` so whatever class objects you put in there are cast to object loosing the methods and properties you have in the class(es).  For instance, `System.Object` doesnt have a `LaunchIE` method defined which *sounds like* what the infamous  "doesnt work" might mean.

Answer (score 0):

- use same function to handle all click event in a for loop.:

  1. for i= 0 to buttonsCount-1
  2. dim temp=i
  3. AddHandler buttons(temp).click,sub(s,args) forms(temp).Show()
  4. next